# Several entities having a one to many relation with one specific entity

Tags: php, sql, symfony, database-design, doctrine-orm

Imagine a scenario where we have **companies**, **bank accounts**, and **customers**. Both companies and customers can have many bank accounts but a bank account can belong to either only one customer or one company. I'd like to know the best way to design such a database that will not involve complicated queries or business logic especially when it comes to the point where we need to delete a bank account from the database.

One solution I've seen is to reference the id's of bank accounts as a JSON string array on either companies or customers like this:

```
In customer or company
======================
id    name  bank_account
1     Bob   [2,3,4,5]
```

It's not a bad solution but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this.

**NB:**
I'm building the application using [Symfony 2.7.5](https://symfony.com/) and therefore using the [Doctrine ORM](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html) library.

Comment: If it is mySQL, use `InnoDB` tables with correctly setup foreign key dependencies - using `cascade` for `update` and `delete` - that will allow you to delete records and any dependent records in other tables will then also be deleted because of the dependency

Comment: @RamRaider I think that would be applicable if we only had one entity with a one to many relation with bank accounts but I don't see how that can be applied here.

Comment: It can be applied if both entities have a common ancestor, see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to handle this is to have both companies and customers inherit from a common ancestor, say users (take a look at [doctrine inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html)). Then there would be a one to many relationship between users and bank accounts, which is really easy to implement and would take care of all your dependencies.

Comment: I agree. Was writing a similar answer. A table for the users, a table for the bank account detail and one that match userid and bank account. So that he can also delete/change  the match with a single query without deleting the bank account

Comment: You don´t even need the third table. Doctrine One to Many relationships are implemented using a foreign key in the master entity. And Doctrine will take care of all the interactions like deleting associated entities if you configure your cascade items correctly

Comment: yes. I know. Mine was just a way to add another possible solution for the problem. :)